# How to print a character at a particular offset within a register?

Tags: assembly, memory, gdb

I just wanted to know if there was a command within the Unix gdb debugger to print an individual character at a particular offset in the register.

For instance,

If I wanted to know what character of a string was in `0x9(%rdi)` how would I display that?

would it be something similar to `x/c $rdi,9` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need not at an offset "within" a register, but rather you need to read memory pointed to by a register, with a given offset. This can be done this way:

```
x/c $rdi+9
```

Generally, the address for the `x` command is just an expression with a numeric value. The `$rdi` here is simply the value of the register `RDI`, to which the constant `9` is added.